# Как в <textarea> сделать так, чтобы при вводе текста только первая буква в предложении была заглавной?

Tags: html, css, textarea

Добрый день.

Вопрос: При вводе текста строчными буквами в `<textarea>` сделать так, чтобы только первая буква в предложении была заглавной?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

С помощью css такое может решить только атрибут [autocapitalize](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea). Проблема в том, что это не универсальное решение. 
Поэтому такую задачу можно решить только с помощью js. Например так:

```js
$("#someId").on('keyup', function(e) {
    var arr = $(this).val().split('.');
    var result = '';
    for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
        result += arr[x].replace(/^\s+/, '').charAt(0).toUpperCase() + arr[x].replace(/^\s+/, '').slice(1) + '. ';
    }
    $(this).val(result.substring(0, result.length - 2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="someId"></textarea>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, но пока для меня js сложно..))